# Can you use the Find function to search for the content of a cell by using the address?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know if its possible to make excel find the content of a cell by using the address of another. Exemple: Cell B7 = "Potato". Futherdown the column, cell B20= "Potato". Can Excel Select the B20 cell without directly using the word "potato" and just use the "B7" as the info?

I am trying to create a search bar on my sheet. So when i write something on the B7 cell, excel will find the content in the B column. I know that the Find function can find the word directly but it doesnt really work/(didnt find anything online) if i write just the address of a cell.

My current broken code:

Sub FindValue()

```
Dim c As Range

With Worksheets(1).Range("B11:B100")
    Set c = .Find(what:=B7, LookIn:=xlValues)
     Set c = .FindNext(c)
     If Not c Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "not found"
        Do
            c.Offset(2).Selet
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: `what:=Range("B7").value, ...`

Comment: Thank you, apologise for the long post.